# How to print 'and' word. Dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so i have a dictionary inside a list. And list inside that dictionary.

```
travel_log =[
{
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 2,
    "cities": ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"]
},
]
```

i want to print out:

You've been to Moscow and Saint Petersburg.

how?

Answer (score 1):

This would work :

```
print(f"You have been to {travel_log[0]['cities'][0]} and {travel_log[0]['cities'][0]}")
```

Comment: I know but if i don't know how many items in it? How to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
print("You've been to" + " and ".join(travel_log[0]['cities']))
```

Comment: Thank you appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
for country in travel_log:
cities = ""
cities_size = len(country["cities"]) - 1
for idx, city in enumerate(country["cities"]):
    if idx > 0:
        if cities_size == idx:
            cities += " AND "
        else:
            cities += ", "

    cities += city
    
print("You've been to "+cities+" at "+country["country"])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is convenient [`inflect`](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect) package. You need to install it with `pip install inflect`

```
import inflect

travel_log =[
{
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 2,
    "cities": ["Moscow", "Saint Petersburg"]
},
]

p = inflect.engine()
for journey in travel_log:
    print(f"You have been to {p.join(journey['cities'])}")
```

output

```
You have been to Moscow and Saint Petersburg
```

if more than 2 elements it will be, e.g.:

```
You have been to Moscow, Volgograd, and Saint Petersburg
```

The package offers more convenient functionality as well - correctly generate plurals, singular nouns, ordinals, indefinite articles; convert numbers to words.